# How to Fill in django form with a json file?

Tags: json, django, forms, django-forms

I'm building a django system that will receive a file and will return a json file and  some graphics. The graphics is working but now and i need to fill in a django form with a json file.

Basically, when the user make the upload a django form will filled and after that the graphics will return.

How can i do that ?

Comment: Could you add an example of what you want to achieve?

Comment: So, i really i dont know how start because i have a function that will process the file and return graphics and a json file. I already have a django model form and its working, but i want make the upload file, to fill the form and show to user in front-end.